# Set Background Color for a textview

Tags: android, xml

I had a textview with a background rounded corner, I try to change color background programmatically but it doesn't work.

my code :

```
      <TextView
                android:id="@+id/incident_icon"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/soft_grey"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="Inc"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                android:visibility="visible" />
```

and for my rounded corner  I use this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

this is my java code, I try this 2 methods but it doesn't work :

```
1- ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.incident_icon)).setBackgroundColor(mainActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.honeycombish_blue, null));



2-  convertView.findViewById(R.id. incident_icon).setBackgroundResource(R.color.honeycombish_blue);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace Your Textview

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/incident_icon"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Inc"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

Your **Rounded_corner** file `rounded_corner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

Change Your java code like below.

```
TextView incident_icon = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.incident_icon);
Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.rounded_corner);
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.honeycombish_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
incident_icon.setBackground(mDrawable);
```

Comment: Perfect answer without create new shape.

Comment: @stanly it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

**Try :**

Create new file in drawable **honeycombish_blue.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#6666FF" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

here use android:color value to blue. instead white

In java file write

```
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.honeycombish_blue);
```

Remove the [backgroundTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTint) from xml.

Comment: Thank's @Dave, I try it it changes the background but I lost the rounded corner :/

Comment: don't copy paste my ans @VishvaDave

Comment: @VishvaDave i hve checked that u have just copied my and when i update my ans please check your edit history

Comment: it's not copy past you can verify even it's the same answer, thank's anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a drawable file to your Textview.

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
```

In your java code I think you need to set

```
.setBackground(R.drawable.honeycombish_blue);
```

In short make a new drawable file of different color and set it on your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nikunj Patel's answer

```
GradientDrawable mDrawable = (GradientDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.DRAWABLE_LAYOUT);
                    mDrawable.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setBackground(mDrawable);
```